# Measurement of wave-plate phase shift

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, experimental-physics, polarization

I used setup: laser, polarizer set on vertical axis, rotary wave plate, polarizer set on horizontal axis. Then I rotate wave plate to 180 deg on 10 deg step. 0 deg on wave plate is not actually 0 because it was mounted in the holder imprecisely ( 0 deg will be when Power is minimal). So i have a chart with measured points. Can I calculate the value of wave plate phase shift ?

@edit: When wave plate is set on 0 deg, there will be minimum (60 deg on chart) and when we rotate on 40 deg it reach maximum (polarizers axis parallel). So this 40 deg is wave plate phase shift ?

[image: chart]

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following configuration:

- A horizontal polarizer, followed by
- a partial waveplate with a fast axis at angle $\theta$ to the horizontal, with an added phase of $\varphi$ on its slow axis, orthogonal to the fast axis, with finally
- a vertical polarizer

followed by an intensity detector.

The state of the light after the horizontal polarizer is given by $\mathbf E(t)=(1,0)\cos(\omega t)$, which reads as
$$
\mathbf E(t)=\cos(\omega t)\cos(\theta)\hat{\mathbf u}-\cos(\omega t) \sin(\theta)\hat{\mathbf v}
$$
in the waveplate's eigenbasis where $\hat{\mathbf u} = (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$, $\hat{\mathbf v} = (-\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta))$, and this gets delayed to 
$$
\mathbf E(t)=\cos(\omega t)\cos(\theta)\hat{\mathbf u}-\cos(\omega t+\varphi) \sin(\theta)\hat{\mathbf v}
$$
after the waveplate, giving an amplitude at the detector of
$$
E_y(t)=\cos(\omega t)\cos^2(\theta)+\cos(\omega t+\varphi) \sin^2(\theta).
$$
The detected amplitude is therefore
\begin{align}
⟨E_y^2(t)⟩
&=\left<
\left(\cos(\omega t)\cos^2(\theta)+\cos(\omega t+\varphi) \sin^2(\theta)\right)^2
\right>
\\&=
\frac14 \left[
\left(2-\sin^2\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)\right)
+
\sin^2\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right) \cos(4\theta)
\right].
\end{align}
This is sufficient to let you infer the phase $\varphi$ (insofar as that's possible with your configuration) from the relative weights of the constant and $\cos(4\theta)$ Fourier coefficients of your data's dependence on the waveplate alignment angle $\theta$.

(On the other hand, (i) the format you give for the data is insufficient to tell what the horizontal axis is, and (ii) your data is pretty far from the clean sinusoid that would be expected from your description, so there's almost certainly other things going on in your experiment (i.e. at the very least some very considerable experimental noise) which you should mitigate / estimate / consider / handle appropriately.)